# After migration from SharePoint 2010 to 2013 Command UI Handler Command Action is not working for the Custom button due to the error mentioned below

Tags: sharepoint-server, visual-studio-2013

We have custom buttons in the ribbon. Button will be enabled based on the status.

CommandUIHandler is are working well for All button except for Submit and Resubmit buttons after migrating from SharePoint 2010 to 2013.
When we click on Submit button[image],we are finding the below error in Console.
[image]

When we click on sp.js to see the error, The below mentioned error is appeared.
[image]

Because of this error, The CommandUIHandler is not running
[image]

We didn't find any solution related to this issue,Please let me know the solution to the above issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have no source for this project?

Comment: May I know what sources do you mean?